# How to send data into server

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I want to send data into server through login page. I am giving the code..

```
NSString *uname= txt_name.text;

//Here you place your URL Link
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/powerplay/insert2.php?name=%@",uname]]; 

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    NSLog(@"connection successful",uname);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Failed");
}
```

by above code i can connect with the server but i really unable to post my data into my Xcode console by which i can see that i am able to send server properly.

Comment: post your insert2.php please

Comment: The link is not valid. But i just want to print my input data in my Xcode console at run time

Comment: You aren't sending any data - you're just connecting to a URL. Where is the code that you are using to actually send data?

Comment: Yes i am trying but i do not the specific code by which i can print into my Xcode console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post data through json in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085615/how-to-post-data-through-json-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see data coming back from your server (that is, assuming your server is sending back some), you've already set "`self`" to be the delegate for your NSURLConnection.

Which means all you have to do is implement [the NSURLConnectionDelegate method `connection:didReceiveData:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveData%3a) and you can print out the incoming data to your Xcode console.

For example:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"received data %ld %@", [data length], [data description]);
}
```