# How to post data through json in iOS

Tags: iphone

I have attempted to post data into server through json. Suppose i have just one field named username into my xib. Now i am posting this data into server. I have written this code 
NSString *uname=txt_name.text;

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mypath/index.php?params=123"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// NSString *postString = @"Email=me@test.com";

[request setValue:[NSString
                   stringWithFormat:@"%d", [uname length]]
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[request setHTTPBody:[uname
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc]
 initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSLog(@"text",uname);
```

But i do not know the data is posting or not. I want to post my input data into console of in Xcode but there nothing is showing. What the reason..? Whats wrong is going on..?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following request:

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = @{@"uname": <YOUR_UNAME>};

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mypath/index.php?params=123"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

To ensure the server have got your data use

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
    ...........
}
```

In case of success you will get *statusCode* = 200.

Comment: [request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: undeclared identifier 'request'

Comment: Your NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mypath/index.php?params=123"]]; is supposed by default

Comment: Thanks males..But its running without error but printing the following in my Xcode console libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.. how can i see that i have submitted my data successfully

Comment: At which place of code do you get this error? Try to set exceptions breakpoint and enable Zombie objects.

Comment: data is not submitted properly males.. I can't print the value in my Xcode console

Comment: I don't understand at what point of code you have a problem. Using debugger at what line have you got exception?

Comment: Np exception and nothing error. My question is that how can i understand that my input data is submitted properly into server..? Thats why i have printed this into my Xcode console by NSLOG method..but there nothing is printed. It means data is not posted properly

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your Url.php?&Username=%@",username];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);
        NSString *str1 = @"1";
        if ([str isEqualToString:str1 ])
        {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Successfully" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Try Again" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Later" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
            alert.tag = 1;
            [alert show];
        }
```

Don't need to use JSON you can do this without JSON in a esay way!!!

Comment: I am trying but code is not working. Data is not submitted properly.. Try again is showing in my Xcode console. What should i do.?

Comment: i think you have to post only user name right. i added my code and please try to run same url in your browsser and check your server response it check your server side code is right or not

Comment: and one more thing is that in my case if server response 1 that means success and if 0 than failuer

Comment: I have tried but its showing that value is not catcher properly by url thats why the following things are printed 2014-01-13 13:34:44.259 sample_json[1305:70b] your Url.php?&Username=(null)
2014-01-13 13:34:44.327 sample_json[1305:70b] responseData: (null)
2014-01-13 13:34:44.328 sample_json[1305:70b] responseData:

Comment: I have taken my text field as NSSTRING *uname= txt_name.text

Comment: don't use this "NSSTRING *uname= txt_name.text" simply try this NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your Url.php?&Username=%@",txt_name.text];
in your url your user name is null so try this

Comment: same thing is happening

Comment: I have done.. But same thing is happening.. null value is accepting

Comment: 2014-01-13 13:49:34.187 sample_json[1559:70b] your Url.php?&Username=(null)
2014-01-13 13:49:34.260 sample_json[1559:70b] responseData: (null)
2014-01-13 13:49:34.261 sample_json[1559:70b] responseData:

Comment: would you doing IBoutlate to you text field if not please share your project with me i will help you.

Comment: in viewController.h UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txt_name;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_name;
- (IBAction)button_send:(id)sender;

Comment: did you NSlog your txt_name.text see if text is printing is console

Comment: then same as you have written avobe